# How do I display an entry's tag?

Tags: templating, tags

I want to display an entry's tag next its title in a list of entries, and on the entry's detail page. For example, for a blog. How do I do that?

Comment: Same goes for categories? {% for category in entry.categoryField %} {{ category }} {% endfor %} And how would we separate tags/categories with commas? Cheers, Rey

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To list all tags on a particular entry use:

```
{% for tag in entry.tagField %}
    {{ tag }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you only want the first tag you can just use:

```
{{ entry.tagField.first }}
```